# Git: working file is different than last commit without having any commit for the changes

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a file where:

The previous version of the file, with commit (`ABC` for example) is correct
***however*** the current (working file), compared to the previous version (using gitlens on vs code), lost many changes that I want to keep.

The problem is that I want to find & revert the commit that made the wrong changes (the one that affected the working file) but the last commit I can see for the working file is (commit `ABC`, which is the correct version)

## How do I get the commit (or merge commit) that caused the file to be in the wrong state?

**Notes:**

1. My git status: `nothing to commit, working tree clean`
2. I found the last commits for the file mentioned using:

   `git log --follow -- full_path_to_file` which show commit `ABC`
   (where the file is in the correct state)
3. I think this might be related to a git merge with conflicts (while pulling `master branch` into this `feature branch` that I am working on) that was handled incorrectly, where someone took the  the old version of the files instead of taking the updated version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here that led to this, was running `git log --follow -- full_path_to_file`

By running instead `git log full_path_to_file` ( instead of the above), it has shown the commit that resulted in the file (which has the incorrect/undesired state)

By checking that merge, it was merging two changes (which both didn't have the new changes that I am missing, causing that issue)